# Eloquent ralationship in laravel not working and following error is occuring

Tags: php

when I try to execute this code give me error help me and give me some solution.[This is error thata i am gonna facing in eloquent realtion shupip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kov7.png)

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.

Comment: Also, please don't post code as image, but as text. Only by this it is possible for others having a similar problem to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might missed something, First check if "TASK" model is called in your controller,2nd it might be Your "TASK" model is not existed if so, created a model and name it Task.